# Identify text inside div class bypassing span class

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, selenium

I'm using Selenium in Visual Studio. Writing a testcase where I want to open up a drop-down menu. I want to identify the menu using the unique name for it.

The code looks like this:

```
<div class="mat-select-value">
   <span class="mat-select-placeholder ng-tns-c34-170 ng-star-inserted">
   UniqueTextID
   </span>
</div>
```

My normal solution for this is this:

```
"//span[contains(@class,'mat-select-placeholder ng-tns-c34-170 ng-star-inserted')][contains(text(),'UniqueTextID')]"
```

The problem is that the span class: "mat-select-placeholder ng-tns-c34-170 ng-star-inserted" is not always the same. Every time the page is loaded again the numbers "c34-170" will change to a new set of numbers.

My question is: Is it possible to identify the "UniqueTextID" by just specifying the div class: "mat-select-value" skipping the span class?

Something like this:

```
"//div[contains(@class,'mat-select-value')][contains(text(),'UniqueTextID')]"
```

Or, if I have to specify the span class, is it possible to just add the start of the span class, i.e the part that does not change every time: "mat-select-placeholder"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the span tag.if you dont want to use class attribute you can use text value only like.

```
//div[contains(@class,'mat-select-value')]/span[contains(text(),'UniqueTextID')]
```

OR

```
//div[contains(@class,'mat-select-value')]/span[contains(.,'UniqueTextID')]
```

Or if you want use span tag with class attribute as well use `starts-with`

```
"//div[contains(@class,'mat-select-value')]/span[starts-with(@class,'mat-select-placeholder ng-tns-')][contains(text(),'UniqueTextID')]"
```